# Can I get the iOS 5 SDK on Xcode 3.2.6?

Tags: xcode, ios5

I can't upgrade to Xcode 4 because I am still running Snow Leopard and my computer doesn't have the hardware to support Lion. Is there anyway I can get the iOS 5 SDK still? I checked on Apple's site, but I only see iOS 4.2 for Xcode 3.2.6.

Comment: FYI: XCode 4.0 runs perfectly fine on Snow Leopard (this won't help you with iOS 5, though)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, Xcode 4.2 with SDK 5 works fine on Snow Leopard.  You can download it from the iOS Dev Center.  You need to have a **paid** developer account to see these versions of Xcode.  It's right below Xcode 4.2.1 for Lion (as of 2011-12-13):

**[Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#downloads)**

[image: screen shot of downloads page]

Comment: That build doesn't seem to be there anymore.  Any way to get the old versions?

Comment: Are you really sure? I can just find the 3.x version for Snow Leopard with SDK 4.x. The 4.x version of Xcode is just available for Lion (https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

Comment: Yes, it's still [there](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#downloads). XCode 4.2 for Snow Leopard is right below 4.2.1 for Lion, make sure you're on the `iOS 5 SDK` tab, not the beta tab, and scroll down 2/3 of the page.

Comment: @Jan: another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8240966/154803) says that if you haven't joined the developer program you will only see XCode 3.2.  Could that be what's happening?

Comment: @progrmr: Yes, now I have seen it. I can confirm, that you need a **paid** account (as you now highlight in your answer) to get that version. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't join the iOS Developer Program, the link to download Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard will not be available, so NKijak is right. If you create a developer account but don't pay for the Dev Program you can only access the 3.2 version of Xcode in Snow Leopard. I've accessed the Downloads page with both types of account to test this, so either pay and join the Dev Program or get stuck with iOS 4 (or borrow an account just to download Xcode)

Comment: Good catch!  I didn't realize you could access that downloads page without a *paid* developer account.